# Сильно ли будет бить по производительности смена типа текстуры в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Сменив из списка "Texture type" значение с "default" на "Cursor" или "Sprite (2d and UI)" получаю намного более приемлемый результат, нежели чем на "default" с увеличенным сглаживанием. Вопрос, такой результат получается чрезмерной нагрузкой (по сравнению с "default") на производительность? (скрины для примера)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Включите в правом верхнем углу статистику, посмотрите сколько нагружен компьютер.

Comment: Уже смотрел, по FPS разницы мне не видно, но ведь есть разительная разница в отображении и потому, думаю, что на что-то такое отображение может влиять, а может там иные просчёты...

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас включилась фильтрация текстур, на десктопные GPU это никак не повлияет (разве что речь не про доисторические карты). На телефонах, возможно, могут быть просадки при больших значениях фильтрации, тут уже надо профилировать.